# unity3d Space Shooter life system collision not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

As I am new to Unity3D and started with Space Shooter tutorial. Now I am unable to create a simple life system for the space ship, probably, it's a silly mistake but I've been on it for few hours already, searching for the solution.

The OnTriggerEnter code is:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag ("Boundary") || other.CompareTag ("Enemy"))
    {
        return;   
    } 

    if (explosion != null) //hit object explosion
    {
        Instantiate (explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    } 
    if (other.tag == "Player" && playerHealth >= 1) {
        playerHealth--;
        gameController.SubLive (playerHealth);
    }

    if (other.tag == "Player" && playerHealth <= 0) {
        Instantiate (playerExplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        gameController.GameOver ();
    } 
    Destroy (gameObject); //destroy hit object
    gameController.AddScore (scoreValue);
    /**/ 
}
```

I've found that the solution is to decrement player health every time collision happens, however, it does only work the first time once player ship collides with asteroid or enemy ship. The triggers are player ship, enemy ship and bolts (shot from ships). All of the objects has rigidbody. Could you please suggest what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

You can find non-edited Space Shooter script [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/extending-space-shooter-enemies-more-hazards?playlist=17147)

Comment: What does `gameController.SubLive` do and where does `playerHealth` come from? Also, does the explosion with the collided object happen but not the subtraction of health, or does neither happen?

Comment: Calls SubLive function from gameController scrip that updates GUI with the health left. I declare `playerHealth = 3` in `void Start()` function and `private int playerHealth;` in beginning of script class. Once player ship hits enemy ship/asteroid it takes away 1 life and `GUIText` show as 2 left. However, afterwards I can hit as many enemy objects as I want with player ship (and destroy them) neither explosion of player ship is initiated, neither life `GUIText` drops lower than 2.

Comment: But this script itself is attached to asteroids, right?

Comment: Yes, it's attached to asteroids/enemy ship.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh! After getting some rest and coming back with a fresh mind I managed to solve it myself! (Was easier that i thought, though!)

```
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag ("Boundary") || other.CompareTag ("Enemy"))
    {
        return;   
    }

    if (explosion != null) 
    {
        Instantiate (explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }

    if (other.tag == "Bolt") 
    {
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
    }

    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        gameController.SubLive (); //if player ship collides asteroid or enemy ship reduces 1 health
        if (gameController.isDead == true) //explodes ship once playerHealth is 0
        {
            Instantiate (playerExplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
            gameController.GameOver ();
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
        }
    }

    gameController.AddScore (scoreValue);
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Script piece in gameController:

```
<...>   
private int playerHealth;
public bool isDead;
<...>   
void Start ()
{
    playerHealth = 3;
    isDead = false;
}
<...>   
public void SubLive()
{
    playerHealth--;
    UpdateLives ();
    if (playerHealth <= 0) 
    {
        isDead = true;
    }
}

void UpdateLives ()
{
    livesText.text = "Lives: " + playerHealth;
}
```